# Privacy issue with Ctrl + Shift + N (Undo Close Window) in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, privacy

I frequently switch between Chrome and Firefox and so I often mistakenly hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to open a private tab in Firefox and instead it performs the [`Undo Close Window`](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Basic-Browsing/Keyboard-shortcuts-Perform-common-Firefox-tasks-quickly/ta-p/3866#w_windows-tabs) function to open or restore the last closed window.

Often times I'm surprised at the window that comes up. For example, today I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> in Firefox and I see a pdf banking statement come up from a secure major U.S. banking site I logged out of yesterday.

If I copy and paste the url for this window into a new Firefox tab then the site requires a login.

How is this happening? Is this a security hole? And is there some way to disable this feature?

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-N in Firefox open the most recently closed window, unfortunately...

Comment: maybe this will suite better on [security.se]

Answer (score 1):

Firefox caches web pages and other content you've accessed recently so it doesn't have to re-retrieve it when you do something like close and reopen a tab. It isn't really a security issue because you accessed the URL previously. If you clicked *reload* you would likely get the login page.

This is one of the reasons most banks suggest you close your browser window on their logout page.

You can [disable the cache in Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/905902) but browsing will get noticeably slower. You could also browse to sites you don't want cached in a Private Browsing window and the cache will be cleared when closing that.

Answer (score 0):

Three solutions here, whenever you are finished with confidential websites (e.g. banking) you could always:

> Option 1

1. Signout on a seperate tab from the one that you were actively using.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>
3. Switch back to the banking tab (the actively used one). <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> might work (depending on  the OS)
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>
6. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>
7. The webpage should now appear as the login screen (effectively locking the unwanted person out).

> Option 2

You could just simply use the [TOR browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tor_Project,_Inc) (an ultra-secure Firefox-based alternative) for banking (or other secure sites), it may not work with all websites and will be very slow, but we're going for security here, right? Using a VPN will also increase your security, then once you close the TOR browser it will wipe everything you had open/saved!! You should be cautious while using the TOR browser while it may lead to inaccurately accused crimes or other charges. (Read the Tor browser link for more information)

> Option 3

Literally, just open your banking/confidential websites in a `secure`/`private` session (like what [Patches](https://superuser.com/a/1244958/946974) said)
See [Firefox Private Windows](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/private-browsing-use-firefox-without-history)

Comment: TOR browser is not "an ultra-secure Firefox-based alternative".

Answer (score 0):

> I figured out a way to reassign Ctrl+Shift+N to *New Private Window* using the [ShortKeys](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/shortkeys/) add-on. I cross-posted the following from [another similar question I just answered](https://superuser.com/questions/1426193/ctrlshiftn-new-private-window-firefox/1724201#1724201).

This add-on solves this problem in 90% of scenarios:

- [**Shortkeys** (Custom Keyboard Shortcuts) for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/shortkeys/) by Peter
  Malecka & Mike Crittenden

**It allows you to create your own custom keyboard shortcuts -- and among those, you can finally invoke a blank *New Private Window* pressing Ctrl+Shift+N**. It is able to override Firefox's own [powerful *Undo Close Window*](https://reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/2xji66/comment/cp0qusi/) (a command which [raised the question author's eyebrows](https://superuser.com/questions/1200329/privacy-issue-with-ctrl-shift-n-undo-close-window-in-firefox), and still remains available just a right-click away) -- and finally makes this combo work just like it does for *New Incognito Window* in Chrome/Edge/Chromium-based browsers and also similar to its equivalent in Apple Safari.
[image]

[Limitations:](https://superuser.com/questions/821594/firefox-change-disable-default-keyboard-shortcut-configuration/1345520#1345520) THE NEW SHORTCUT ONLY WORKS IF YOU ALREADY HAVE AN ACTUAL WEBPAGE LOADED.
**Due to Mozilla Firefox's own "security" measures, it does NOT work on any of the "`about:`" or internal pages (`about:blank`, `about:newtab`, etc.)**, as well as on a new tab, empty windows, downloads/bookmarks manager, pop-up, etc.; as I type this, I also realized **it does not work if the cursor is in an active text input field** -- I have to click the empty blank area of this webpage first, and only then Ctrl+Shift+N will work.

Another limitation: I'm using Firefox on Windows, and **I tried assigning Mac-inspired shortcuts such as Ctrl+, (comma) and Ctrl+. (period) to *Open Settings Page* and *Open Extensions Page* respectively. No idea why, but that didn't work**, sigh (I was able to create these and more for Chrome/Edge for Windows with the extension [Keyboard Shortcuts](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/keyboard-shortcuts/lplcmnhgijkkmflbmhabnccgelffpnog) though, for anyone interested).