# How to disable Ctrl+Q shortcut in Firefox on Linux

Tags: linux, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, ubuntu-unity

Since Firefox 57 there is no way to disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> shortcut by plugin on Linux (see [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1325692)). All workarounds I've found are based on setting the global <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> shortcut to "steal" it from Firefox. But this will disable this shortcut in every application, and I want to disable this shortcut only in Firefox, without affecting any other app.

Is there a way to disable or catch shortcut only for one application? I'm using Ubuntu with Unity.

Comment: Interesting question, but the answer may depend on the use case. Accidental key presses? Kiosk mode?

Comment: @l0b0 Accidental key presses. This is regular PC, nothing fancy.

Comment: In that case, do you have more details? I'm just checking if there is some way the system can be set up to Do What You Want™, such as save the tabs when you quit, to avoid something which I suspect will be a brittle hack.

Comment: @l0b0 I want to prevent closing browser by accidental key presses. There is a too many things are changing after closing browser (closing sessions, terminating connections), I would prefer to prevent closing browser than fixing its effects.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

In `about:config` set preferences.

### Firefox >= 87

```
browser.quitShortcut.disabled true
```

(this setting will take effect with a restart of the browser.)

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=52821

### Firefox >= 65

```
browser.sessionstore.warnOnQuit true
browser.warnOnQuit true
```

[image]

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/ajh9fo/firefox_does_not_warn_me_when_closing_a_private/eevnxm2/)

### Older Firefox

```
browser.showQuitWarning true
browser.warnOnQuit true
```

Tested in all version I've come across 61.0.2-64.0.2 on 64bit Linux (and the 60esr channel on Win10).
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Any constructive feedback with that downvote?

Comment: Thanks, works for me at least on FF 62.0.3 (64-Bit Ubuntu).

Comment: thank you. This is smart solution, without touching anything.

Comment: ^ This is the right answer!

Comment: That doesn't work along with "Restore Previous Session" or "Show my windows and tabs from last time", which is even worse.

Comment: @chefarov can you explain what you mean?  I've seen no problems getting my tabs back after a crash or reboot.

Comment: And now, as of FF 63.0.3 (64-Bit Ubuntu), ctrl-Q once again quits instantly for me, despite both those options being enabled. It's astonishing what a mess they've made of this simple (mis-)feature. Ah well, maybe it will be working again in v64...

Comment: I don't see the `browser.showQuitWarning` on ff quantum 64.0 64bit on linux. `browser.warnOnQuit` is enabled but does nothing?

Comment: Thanks @rofrol for finding the missing piece - some FF versions have changed the relevant key name - just search for "quit" and you should be good.

Comment: In bugfox 65.0.2 this just completely disabled ctrl+q (which is completely fine for me).

Comment: This is not working for me in Firefox 66.0.5 in Manjaro Linux. Will have to deal with `browser.tabs.warnOnClose;true` now. Related: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=502908#c73

Comment: Selected answer no longer resolves the issue.

Comment: still works with Firefox 68.0

Comment: Does not work anymore on Firefox 69.0.2 in Archlinux. `browser.showQuitWarning` is missing and both `browser.warnOnQuit` and `browser.sessionstore.warnOnQuit` seem to be ignored.

Comment: After a little more digging, it turns out it's now necessary to enable `Preferences > General > Startup > Restore previous session` for `Warn you when quitting the browser` to work.

Comment: @JoL Thanks a lot, this should be part of the answer for sure!

Comment: In Firefox 87 (Nightly at time of writing) I added the preference `browser.quitShortcut.disabled`. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=52821

Comment: @evilpie "Opened 21 years ago Closed 1 day ago" Whoa! You deserve a medal :)

Comment: For `browser.quitShortcut.disabled true` to take effect, one needs to restart Firefox first.

Comment: Now we need this for Thunderbird. You could add a note in the answer that the first solution will completely disable the shortcut while the 2 others will warn the user before quitting.

Answer (score 22):

tl/dr: assign a global shortcut to Ctrl-Q

In Firefox Quantum, the [`about:config` settings](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/7fehbb/please_give_us_an_option_to_disable_ctrlq/) that used to warn against Firefox closures via an accidental Ctrl-Q keypress no longer work.

**Workaround:** on Arch Linux | XFCE desktop environment (other Linux distros &/or desktops may allow a similar approach):

- Whiskers menu >> All Settings >> Keyboard >> Application Shortcuts >> Add
- Add a new "application", `null`; assign it to the `Ctrl-Q` keypress

  - Update (comment by @justderb): "Using 'true' instead of 'null' is nice if you don't want the error window to pop up."

[image: Firefox - 'disable' Ctrl-Q]

**Invocation:** here, I pressed `Ctrl-Q` in Firefox Quantum v. 60.0.1 (64-bit); instead of quitting Firefox, I get this popup,

[image: Firefox - Ctrl-Q 'disabled']

**Caveat:** this, of course, globally affects all Ctrl-Q keypresses.  However, -- per my own preference -- that shortcoming is outweighed by nullifying those accidental Firefox Ctrl-Q closures (after which I must re-login into websites: GitHub; reddit; ...).

**Update 1**

@crazypyro 's answer also works for me (FF Quantum 63.0 on x86_64 Linux) giving a popup warning if you try to Quit Firefox.  That should be probably regarded as the specific answer, with my solution as a more general workaround.

`about:config` (both of the following set to `true`):

- `browser.showQuitWarning`
- `browser.warnOnQuit`

**Update 2** [2020-03-01]

For some time in Vim I've encountered the occasional and frustrating issue where the terminal "freezes" and I lose keystroke control of **Vim** (requiring me to kill/restart Vim).

After some investigating, it turns out the issue is [Software Flow Control](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/72092/135372) (XON/XOFF flow control). `Ctrl-s` freezes the terminal until `Ctrl-q` is pressed -- which, per my solution presented above, is globally remapped to "dummy application" `true`.

The workaround to this issue is to add the lines

```bsh
# enable Ctrl-s and Ctrl-q:
stty -ixon
```

near the top of your `~/.bashrc`, then open a new terminal and start Vim.

Relevant links/discussion:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72086/ctrl-s-hang-terminal-emulator
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419820/sometimes-my-file-just-freezes-in-my-vi-vim-what-happened
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/478532/why-is-vim-frozen
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72086/ctrl-s-hang-terminal-emulator | ... Before there were keyboards with the scroll lock key `C-s` and `C-q` were the old days "scroll lock toggle". You can disable this functionality by adding `stty ixany` and `stty ixoff -ixon` to your ~/.bashrc [... and restarting terminal]

Comment: Using `true` instead of `null` is nice if you don't want the error window to pop up.

Comment: @justderb: nice!  :-D

Comment: for me in archlinux/kde 5 plasma I could not do global shortcut without choosing an application first - could not be true|null, but thanks to your suggestion i was able to remapped it to toggle microphone - which on work computer is pointless for me anyway.. thanks!

Comment: Mapping CTRL+q in sxhkd also hijacks the shortcut, preventing Firefox to quit.

Comment: Works in Mint 19.

Comment: Works perfectly on Pop_OS 20.04 LTS. No need to change the command to `true`, `null` does not provide any error messages.

Answer (score 9):

## Disable Ctrl+q with userChrome.js in Firefox Quantum

This can be accomplished without an external application by a tiny bit of javascript in your Firefox profile.

As a prerequisite, you must enable userChrome.js (see below, or obtain from the [original GitHub repo](https://github.com/nuchi/firefox-quantum-userchromejs))

After copying the chrome directory and its contents into your user profile, create a file `<profile-dir>/chrome/disable_ctrl_q.uc.js` with the following content:

```
var kqa = document.getElementById('key_quitApplication');
if (kqa) kqa.remove();
```

Lastly, restart Firefox, and ctrl+q will no longer cause the application to exit.

---

## Enabling userChrome.js in Firefox Quantum

For completeness, below are the full contents of the modified chrome files. To enable userChrome javascript, create these two files inside a `chrome` directory within your Firefox profile.

1. Type `about:support` in the address bar.
2. Under **Application Basics >  Profile Directory** click the **Open Directory** button to open your Firefox profile directory.
3. Within the profile directory, make a new directory called `chrome`
4. Within the `chrome` directory, create new files `userChrome.css` and `userChrome.xml` with the contents listed below.
5. Restart Firefox (you probably also want to create the .uc.js file above if you're following these steps to disable ctrl+q)

### userChrome.css

```
/* Copyright (c) 2017 Haggai Nuchi
Available for use under the MIT License:
https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
*/
@namespace url(http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul);
toolbarbutton#alltabs-button {
    -moz-binding: url("userChrome.xml#js");
}
```

### userChrome.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Copyright (c) 2017 Haggai Nuchi
Available for use under the MIT License:
https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 -->

<bindings id="generalBindings"
   xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/xbl"
   xmlns:xul="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
   xmlns:xbl="http://www.mozilla.org/xbl">

  <binding id="js" extends="chrome://global/content/bindings/toolbarbutton.xml#menu">
    <implementation>
        <constructor><![CDATA[
            function makeRelativePathURI(name) {
              let absolutePath = Components.stack.filename;
              return absolutePath.substring(0, absolutePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) + name;
            }
            // The following code executes in the browser context,
            // i.e. chrome://browser/content/browser.xul
            Services.scriptloader.loadSubScript(makeRelativePathURI("userChrome.js"), window);
        ]]></constructor>
    </implementation>
  </binding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Firefox 62

Comment: It works with the latest stable, Firefox 61. Hopefully 62 is fixed before it leaves beta.

Comment: I now use the solution from CrazyPyro https://superuser.com/a/1352295/308508

Comment: Doesn't work in 69.0.2 (not beta). Also, `document.getElementById('key_quitApplication')` returns null. Has the name of this element changed?

Comment: @tsbertalan After updating from 66 to 84, that setting in my userChrome.js also didn't work anymore. However, after trying to find whether the name changed and finding that it didn't change, I finally found the reason: userChrome.js is not loaded anymore. I installed [this patch](https://github.com/Izheil/Quantum-Nox-Firefox-Dark-Full-Theme/tree/master/Multirow%20and%20other%20functions/JS%20Loader) to allow JS injection and put those lines of code into `/chrome/custom-shortcuts.uc.js` (any chrome/*.uc.js is loaded) and it works again!

Answer (score 9):

An ugly, but simple and effective workaround is always keeping a page open that has an active `onbeforeunload` handler, i.e. will trigger the "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved." dialog when you attempt to close it.

That way, if you accidentally try to CTRL+Q, you will receive that dialog, and can choose "stay on this page" to cancel the exit.

Edit: [Custom page I made just for this purpose](https://janschejbal.github.io/disable-ctrl-q/)

**Edit: as of 2020-05-10 / Firefox 76 (and likely quite some time before that), the built-in warning dialog works for me with these settings:**

[image: restore previous session checked, warn you when quitting the browser checked]

Since the bug is still untouched, I have no idea if this is actually fixed or if it just happened to start working due to some list randomly being in the right order or something. If you're still experiencing this issue after the date of this edit, would you mind leaving a comment confirming that the settings are set the same way, the Firefox version you're using, and the OS?

Comment: nice hacker spirit there!

Comment: Thanks! Added a link to my implementation.

Comment: Thanks for this. Works for me, and so cheezy I love it (: It's astounding to me that FF has messed up this simple thing.

Answer (score 7):

I was able get what I need with [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey). After installation I created empty script with assigned <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> as "Hotkey" and `.*Firefox` as "Window filter".

[image]

Then in AutoKey preferences I added it to autostart and disabled notification icon, so it becomes transparent for me.

[image]

I used it for a few hours and it looks promising - no false-positives or missed catches so far. Right now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> does not working for Firefox, but it works perfectly fine in PhpStorm for example.

---

In addition [bug 1215061](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1215061#c66) gives some hope that this will be easier in future and Firefox will finally get some decent keyboard shortcuts settings.

Answer (score 1):

I have been plagued by this on and off through varoius firefox versions, too.

Here is one solution that always works, and works for other browsers too:

Keep a tab open with this page (you can save it locally): https://janschejbal.github.io/disable-ctrl-q/

You have to click the button on that page once so firefox thinks something important is going on there, but then you can completely forget about it.

Read the page for an explanation.

It has saved me a good handful of times (: